# Php Upload Class issue with file over 6Mb

Tags: php, image, class, upload

I'm working on a photo album where a user can upload their own pictures. I want the user to be able to send any size pictures to the website and if it is over 5Mb it gets processed to 5Mb with the php upload class.

The upload of the file works for any picture size smaller than the configuration in the php.ini file which is at 30Mb. The original picture gets uploaded to a temporary folder for it to be processed.

I am easily able to process the picture to create the thumb and the main picture but when I want to generate the large file (processed to 5Mb for users to download) it doesn't work.

Here is the piece of code I'm using for processing the pictures:

```
$handle = new upload("../".$path_picture_temp.$this->imgName);

    if ($handle->uploaded) {
      $handle->image_convert         = 'jpg';
      $handle->jpeg_size             = 5242880;
      $handle->process("../".$path_picture_full);
    }
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
      $handle->image_resize         = true;
      $handle->image_x              = 231;
      $handle->image_y              = 153;
      $handle->image_ratio_crop     = true;
      $handle->image_convert        = 'jpg';
      $handle->jpeg_quality         = 95;
      $handle->process("../".$path_picture_thumb);
    }
    if ($handle->uploaded) {
      $handle->image_resize         = true;
      $handle->image_x              = 1000;
      $handle->image_y              = 1000;
      $handle->image_ratio          = true;
      $handle->image_convert        = 'jpg';
      $handle->jpeg_quality         = 95;
      $handle->process("../".$path_picture_main);
    }
```

When I upload a picture under 6Mb it works even if it is slow, but if I upload a picture over 6Mb it doesn't work and it doesn't even process anything.

When I get ride of the first part for the processing of the large picture everything works fine for any file size. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening ?

Comment: are there any errors? do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Do you know how much time it takes for your files under 6Mb? Maybe when the size is over 6Mb the processing exceeds the `max_execution_time` of the script.

Comment: @bjauy I'm trying it now to get the error reporting to work.

Comment: @florian I also thought it was that, it takes around 10 seconds to generate when everything works (picture under 6Mb) but when I try with bigger files it instantly goes to the end of the function and redirects itself, it doesn't process anything, it is instantaneous.

Comment: oh, and one more question: you write about php.ini configuration, are you sure both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are set to 30M?

Comment: @bjauy yes `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are both set to 30M. And I can't figure out a way to get the error reporting inside my php class. I'm still going to try it a little while.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GD and imagcreatefromjpeg() function, this maybe will solve your problem:
[PHP GD imagecreatefromjpeg cant handle big size image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381228/php-gd-imagecreatefromjpeg-cant-handle-big-size-image)

Comment: Note that if you are using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` function, even though your picture size is 5MB, it could be bigger than your `memory_limit` when processed.

Comment: I pushed the memory_limit up to 500M but still no change, I also tried 1000M and same story.